# VBA Excel: Getting result for multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get the result of different cells based on a preset `if` statement
I am receiving the result in multiple message boxes, and the result for all cells is being calculated based on the first statement check up. How can i receive all results in a single `msgbox`and allow the function to check every single cell in the range?

```
Dim rcell As Range
For Each rcell In Vou_Summary.Range("I5:I16")
    If 0 < rcell <= 2.5 Then
        MsgBox rcell.Cells.Offset(0, -3).Value & " Is Critical", vbOKOnly, "Notice!"
    ElseIf 2.5 < rcell <= 4 Then
        MsgBox rcell.Cells.Offset(0, -3).Value & " Requires PR Placement", vbOKOnly, "Notice!"
    ElseIf rcell >= 7 Then
        MsgBox rcell.Cells.Offset(0, -3).Value & " Is Oversupplied", vbOKOnly, "Notice!"
    Else
End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a String variable first. Don't throw a MsgBox but save the results into the variable. Past the `End If` statement show the MsgBox and pass the string variable as the content.

Better, you can use a [String Builder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/67596/28366) to make it work about 1000 times faster than the default VBA concatenation ;)